# Identify 2x Plant Species

Tags: identification

I've recently visited the Royal Botanic Garden Edinburgh and seen these two plants in the image below. I was trying to identify the plants in this section for a project, and most came with a little name-plate (thank you RBGE) but these two didn't (not that I could see). Any ideas anyone?

To clarify; this section contains native and non-native species from Scotland, China, Japan, Canada, America, and possibly other places, so these species really could be from anywhere!

--- Edit ---

Top species: *Hosta sieboldiana var. elegans*

Bottom species: Unidentified

Thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: Welcome. It's generally best to ask one question per question, with the way the site works. Take the [tour]

Answer (score 3):

The bottom plant seems to be a species of Rodgersia, most probably [Rodgersia pinnata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodgersia_pinnata)

Answer (score 2):

Trust me to spend an hour looking and then stumble upon one of the two plants almost straight after posting a question...

I believe the plant in the upper half of the image is a *Hosta sieboldiana* (Giant Blue Hosta).

Comment: And perhaps specifically *c.v.* Elegans (from Japan, but widely spread and popular) https://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=d340